# Prove that values of $x$ in $19x + 34y = 1,$ repeat in a period of $34.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to show a pattern to integer values in $19x + 34y = 1.$

I've been rewriting it was $34y \bmod 19 = 1,$ and since $34y = 19y + 15y,$ $$34y\equiv 15y \pmod {19}.$$

For $15y \bmod 19 = 1,$ I've just guessed and checked every value upwards, where I got $y = 14.$

So I write that $y$ will repeat with period $19$ (because we did modulo $19$ ), and that it will always take the form of $y = 19n + 14.$

How do I prove that I can take the original equation and turn it into a modular equation? I've been assuming it works but is there a sequence of equations that visually shows it?

Comment: Everything you did is correct and seems rigorous enough to me. Which step in particular are you unsure about? Note that, for a systematic solution, the extended euclidean algorithm seems suitable.

Comment: I've read about the Euclidean algorithm for this, but I don't see how I can get 14 from using 19 and 34. The remainders for each line is 15,4,3,1,0.

Comment: The title says "values of $x$" which repeat with period $34$ but the rest of the question is about values of $y$ which repeat with period $19$.

Comment: I was just showing 'y' because a similar process should be available to 'x'. I'm about to accept the answer down below.

Comment: @Knocker379 I think you are performing the "standard", non-extended Euclidean algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Description)

Comment: I find the "guess and check" step is usually easier with smaller numbers. We have $34 \equiv 15 \equiv -4 \pmod{19}.$ I want to multiply $4$ (never mind the sign for the moment) by something that will come out to either $1$ or $-1$ modulo $19.$ Starting with $19 \pm 1,$ I see that $19+1 = 20 = 4 \times 5.$ At this point I remember I actually have $-4$, so to get the product $20$ I need to multiply by $-5$, whereas $-5 \equiv 14 \pmod{19},$ so $14$ is an answer. (Or I could just use $-5$, since any number $y=19n - 5$ is also $y=19m+14.$)

Comment: Ah I see, so doing the extended version gets me to gcd(19,34) = 1, s = 9, and t= 5, so I know that y = 19n + 5, which is equal to the 19n - 14, which is why 14 * 15 mod 19 = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach without modular arithmetic.

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ be a solution to the equation $19x+34y=1.$ Therefore, $$19x_0+34y_0=1$$
Adding and subtracting $19\cdot 34$,
$$19x_0+34y_0+19\cdot 34-19\cdot 34\\=19(x_0+34)+34(y_0-19)=1.$$
Hence, we have shown that if $(x_0,\;y_0)$ is a solution, $(x_0+34,\;y_0-19)$ is also a solution.

Comment: @Knocker379 Hope it helps :)

Comment: It did! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I don't need proof that these are the only solutions, just proof that they repeat. I know of 2 forms of 'x' and 2 forms of 'y' that I solve for in these types of equations

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I have shown that $x$ repeats in a period of $34$ which was my interpretation of the question.